# Creation of Spatial Index is taking too long on SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial, spatial-query, spatial-index

I have a table with schema as below on SQL Server 2016.I am trying to create spatial index on the geography column as `create spatial index spatindex on OSM_Nodes(longlat);`. But it's been running from hours. Not sure what's the issue. I stopped the execution multiple times and tried adding a new spatial index directly by right clicking on Indexes folder under table but still the same issue.

Table Schema:

```
create table OSM_Nodes(
nodeid int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
latitude float,
longitude float,
longlat geography
);
```

Comment: What is your table size? What have you tried to diagnose the issue?

Comment: And what is the spec of the server?

Comment: In addition to @Alex's questions, I'd also be interested to know if you specified `with (online = on)` for the index creation. It could be that your operation is just blocked!

Comment: @Alex The table size is just over half a million rows.

Comment: @BenThul, No i haven't specified  `with (online =on)` . But I don't know if it makes sense, when I re ran  `exec sp_updatestats` and ran the query to create spatial index, it worked after executing for about 10 to 15 minutes. Still not sure why the issue happened. Also, I would like to know if 15 minutes is too long for query execution.

Comment: I have found a Microsoft patch that may be relevant: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2887888/fix-slow-performance-in-sql-server-when-you-build-an-index-on-a-spatia

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a spatial index on a location table I use.

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [SIndx_Geo] ON [my].[Locations]
(
    [Geo]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_2 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_3 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_4 = MEDIUM)
```

My query performance improved from 45 seconds to 0.4 seconds on over 1 million rows. The process only took a few seconds to run